# php command is not recognized in wamp

Tags: php, windows, sockets, wampserver

I'm working on websocket. I came across this article, and simply downloaded their file and try running it in my localhost.
https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket

What I understand is, they want to sue local server's websocket server.

But I have problem in starting up the server. I'm using windows 10 with wamp 2.2. As I checked webscket is enabled in my php.ini's extention.

I followed this example to cmd the right path to start it but to no avail:
https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket/comment-page-1#comment-5593

It says **'php.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external ...**

I then searched online again, thus set the path to my php folder in the system's environment variable. The path is: `C:\wamp\bin\php`. Then I closed the cmd and relaunched. Nothing worked out. The same error shows up.

This is what I did on cmd:
1) `cd C:\wamp\bin\php`
2) `php.exe -q C:\projects\myfolder\server.php`

Please help me to connect to wamp server's websocket to run the example I've downloaded.In the console, the error shown is:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9000/demo/server.php' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from this site: http://rodrixar.blogspot.my/2011/07/how-to-run-php-sockets-in-wamp.html

I did the following,

1) open cmd
2) cd C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.19
3)php.exe -q C:\projects\mysite\server.php
4) Firewall open up and allow access for CLI
5) now connection made already..